# DataContractSerializer vs XmlSerializer: Pros and Cons of each serializer

Tags: .net, serialization

My desktop application serializes objects using `XmlSerializer`. I was suggested to leverage `DataContractSerializer` instead.
Under which scenarios should I use `DataContractSerializer`?

Many thanks

Comments.
1. The output XML file is stored locally. No other applications deserialize objects from that XML file.
2. My application runs with .NET Framework 3.5 SP1.

Comment: Also see [datacontract-vs-xmltype](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/624111/datacontract-vs-xmltype)

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Dan Rigsby has the ultimate post on this - go read it!

[XmlSerializer vs. DataContractSerializer (web archive)](http://web.archive.org/web/20130430190551/http://www.danrigsby.com/blog/index.php/2008/03/07/xmlserializer-vs-datacontractserializer-serialization-in-wcf/)

He says all there is to say, and in a very convincing way.

In short:

XmlSerializer:

- has been around for a long time
- is "opt-out"; everything public gets serialized, unless you tell it not to ([XmlIgnore])

DataContractSerializer is:

- the new kid in town
- optimized for speed (about 10% faster than XmlSerializer, typically)
- "opt-in" - only stuff you specifically mark as `[DataMember]` will be serialized
- but anything marked with `[DataMember]` will be serialized - whether it's `public` or `private`
- doesn't support XML attributes (for speed reasons)

Comment: @Paul-SebastianManole: the DataContractSerializer doesn't support XML attributes - for speed reasons. What's to elaborate?

Comment: Well, I'm new to .NET. I was about to go on using XmlSerializer since I found a few tutorials online. But then I found DataContractSerializer on MSDN which seems to be linked to WCF. What I want to do is, deserialize some XML into a plain object which would allow me access to an XML element and its attributes because I want to serialize those objects later, back into an XML document, after I calculate some values for the attributes.

Comment: @Paul-SebastianManole: if your source XML contains attributes on XML elements (like `<Customer Id="42"> ...` ) then you're only option is using the XML serializer

Comment: This might be useful, taken from MSDN: _The XmlSerializer class supports a much narrower set of types than the DataContractSerializer class, but allows much more control over the resulting XML and supports much more of the XML Schema definition language (XSD) standard. It also does not require any declarative attributes on the serializable types... The XmlSerializer class does not support data contract types._ [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733901.aspx).

Comment: You should probably add this to SO as your own question - explain what you want to do, show what you've tried so far, explain where you're stuck or unsure - I'm sure someone will provide an answer!

Comment: @marc_s No longer opt-in for .NET 3.5 SP1 and above.

Comment: @O.O: not **only** opt-in, in .NET 3.5 SP1 and newer - but for me, it's still the **preferred way** of doing things. Allows you to set properties that otherwise cannot be set (like order of serialization, namespaces and much more!)

Comment: @marc_s - hmm, for some reason I am getting properties that have values show up in the xml that do not have [DataMember] attribute.  I guess I don't understand the only part of your comment.

Comment: DCS can serialize private members too which I think is worth mentioning.

Comment: @nawfal: right - anything marked with the `[DataMember]` attribute will be serialized

Comment: Biggest warning about the DataContractSerializer - when deserializing, it cares about the order of the elements and fails silently if they're not in the correct order.  Imho, unless you're using the exact same assemblies at both ends, this makes it unusably dangerous.

Comment: @Pxtl: that's not really a "shortcoming" of the DataContractSerializer - that's the way the XML schema handles `<xs:sequence>` constructs...-

Comment: It's still pretty unexpected behavior if you're used to the more permissive nature of the XmlSerializer.  In this day and age, the user might assume the more Json-like behavior of <xs:all>

Comment: I second @Pxtl, I am serializing to file with a changing schema where there is refactoring on the inherited base classes - I don't care about the order I don't care about web services - I only want backward compatibility in my classes - this is a silent showstopper for me I barely realized before going into production and I am simply thankful for it.

Comment: Note: XmlSerializer does not support the DateTimeOffset type. Just got bitten by this.

Comment: After getting burned by a few things (mainly deserilization order) by the DataContractSerializer, I would recommend staying away from it unless you control both ends of the service and you need your service to be extremely fast.  If you control only the one end and you can't control what the other side is doing the safe bet is the XMLserializer plus those XML attributes that can be seen make documentation of your service a lot easier.